# clipToOutline=true not working when get Bitmap from View

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I have a RecyclerView, ViewHolder has shape background with corners. It showed correct in the real device. I want to take the Bitmap from this. But the clipped view is not show (still shape)
[image: Screenshot with default func in device]

Screenshot with default func in device

[image: Bitmap from programming]

Bitmap from programming

the get Bitmap from View func:

```
fun getBitmapFromView(view: View): Bitmap {
    val locationOfView = IntArray(2)
    view.getLocationInWindow(locationOfView)
    val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    val drawable = view.background
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.draw(canvas)
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    }
    view.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue... Espresso (androidx.test.espresso.screenshot) provides an extension which can capture correct view

```
ViewInteraction.captureToBitmap()
```